# Loading dynamic library in PHP

Tags: php, dll

I tried to execute this command to install Symfony on my localhost

```
php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony.phar
```

I got an error message in my Windows machine regarding this.

> The error message is `PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\php\php\ext\intl.so' - The specified module could not found.`

Answer (score 0):

It is all about the php.ini file. On windows, the dynamic library files usually do not have the extesion .so (linux library) ... you have to have .dll there... and make sure the referenced file exists.

Comment: Thanks @Michal. Why my machine is looking for .so file ??

Comment: I removed comment for these line `extension=php_intl.dll`,  `intl.default_locale = en_utf8` and `intl.error_level = E_WARNING`. But it is not working.

I tried a lot but failed. Please help me.

Comment: Now I changed `extension=php_intl.dll` to `extension=D:\php\php\ext\php_intl.dll`, but situation unchanged.

Comment: There is nothing like `intl.so` in my php.ini. Even I searched the whole directory of XAMPP, but could not find any thing like `intl.so`.